Convert floating-point value to cyclic range?
I'm not sure if I'm using the right terminology, but occasionally I find myself needing to canonicalize a floating-point value to a range in a cyclic manner. (This can be useful, for instance, for values that represent rotations, to special-case rotations by whole quadrants or eliminate redundant rotations by whole turns.)
For example, assuming a cycle range of 1.0, the result should be: 0 <= result < 1.0.
Inputs 0.25, 1.25, 2.25 and so on should all become 0.25.
Of course, this is what the modulo operator % supposedly does:
System.out.println(1.25 % 1); // 0.25

But it can still produce a negative result for negative input:
System.out.println(-1.75 % 1); // -0.75, rather than 0.25 as wanted

So for years I've been writing this pattern whenever I needed this functionality:
x %= range;
if (x < 0) x += range;

Today I discovered a bug: starting from very small negative inputs (e.g., x = -1e-20), it turns out that the floating-point result of x += range rounds up to exactly range, so, out of range.
Which has led to this:
static double cyclic(double x, double range) {
    x %= range;
    if (x < 0) {
        x += range;
        if (x >= range) x = 0;
    }
    return x;
}

Even though each line has a justification for being there, the whole is grotesque. (And it comes in two flavors, one for float and one for double, for double the grotesquery.)
I would like to know:

Is my "cyclic" function above finally robust against all floating-point oddities?

Is there a nicer solution? This doesn't feel like it should be so complex. I feel like I'm missing a trick.



"...it turns out that the floating-point result of x += range rounds up to exactly range, so, out of range."   Have you considered using BigDecimal for this or must you use primtives?

Interesting problem.  The next representable double value less than 1 is 0.9999999999999998 or 1 - 1.11e-16.  So anything greater than the number halfway between them — anything more than 1 − 5.55e-17 — will round up to 1.  So any number that comes out after the modulo step with a value greater than -5.55e-17 will have this problem, and your example -1e-20 definitely fits.

The known workaround is to use a modulo that round the quotient to nearest integer, instead of truncating the quotient.
The result is a modulo in interval (-range/2,range/2] or [-range/2,range/2) depending on the parity of the quotient (odd or even).
This is the purpose of IEEE754 remainder function, std::remainder in C++, IEEEremainder in java (https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_math_ieeeremainder.asp) function name may vary in other languages/math libraries
A correct implementation of such remainder function shall be exact (not subject to rounding errors).

I wasn't previously aware of IEEEremainder but I tried swapping out x % range for Math.IEEEremainder(x, range) and the result is still sometimes negative when x is negative, so I don't see how this simplifies anything.

@Boann: This answer is suggesting you redesign your code to use interval [−½, +½). Yes, that is not what you asked, but it ultimately may result in simpler or better code. It does solve the problem of a calculation producing the undesired endpoint, albeit at the cost of requiring you to change the interval being used. It also improves accuracy, since there is no rounding error in this method. The interval you were using is inherently problematic since the floating-point format cannot represent some of the mathematical results, notably 1+x for a small negative x…

… There may be some reason you need to use [0, 1) and cannot use [−½, +½), but, without that reason given in the question, this answer is a reasonable suggestion that ought to be considered.

It looks like you used to write in Python)
With the division of variables of the double type in Java, everything is not so simple.
System.out.println(1.25 % 1); // 0.25
But pay attention! ==>  System.out.println(1.1 % 1); // 0.10000000000000009

you can get the values of variables after modulo division without using if/if
for example, like this (actually in two lines)
List<Double> ld = List.of(1.25, 2.25, 3.25, -4.25, -5.25);
        for (double value : ld) {
            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat( "#.#" );
            System.out.println(Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(Math.abs(value) % 1)));
        }

or if you write in detail
List<Double> ld = List.of(1.25, 2.25, 3.25, -4.25, -5.25);
            for (double value : ld) {
              double varWithoutSign = Math.abs(value);
              double remainderOfDivision = varWithoutSign % 1;
              DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat( "#.#" );
              String resultStr = decimalFormat.format(remainderOfDivision);
              double result = Double.valueOf(resultStr);
              System.out.println(result);
              }


Using abs like that will result in wrong values.  As the OP stated, an input of -1.75 should yield an output of 0.25.  By the same token, your test inputs of -4.25 and -5.25 should both yield a result of 0.75.

The OP isn't asking about how to format outputs; they're asking about how to bring a floating point number into a particular range.
